# Record mouse position with dlib

Tags: c++, click, mouse, dlib

I am trying to draw a rectangle on screen with dlib. Does anyone know which object provides methods for recording mouse clicks/mouse position on a dlib window?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at drawable.h and see if it is what you are looking for, here's an example from the official documentation: http://dlib.net/dlib/gui_widgets/drawable.h.html.

Comment: Works just fine, because I had little experience with OO C++ I didn't know I must override protected methods to make use of them and create my own class which derives from the abstract one. Thanks! Your answer made me search further on the right path. Now it works.